# How to consume Kafka in CKAN

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, ckan

Is it possible to link a resource in CKAN to a Kafka consume-API? I want to access with the CKAN api the live resource that is published in Kafka in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably write this yourself in a CKAN extension.
For example, I wrote a CKAN-Validator plugin that runs just like the Datapusher but grabs the files, validates them using frictionless goodtables validate function for csv and excel files. If the validation is successful, I push the files into a database where Logstash pulls data from and begins the journey to Elasticsearch. I chose GoodTables over MessyTables for a variety of reason.

I think you can write a background job that pulls the data from Kafka consume-API and possibly pushes it into the CKAN datastore.

You should have a look at the `ckan-service-provider` library.

That's what I used to write mine.

Here's a link to it on github: https://github.com/ckan/ckan-service-provider